# Inverse of the covariance of the estimate of a covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, random-matrices

I have a covariance matrix, $V_{ij}$, which (for reasons that aren't important) I'm going to call the visibilities.  I have an estimator for the visibilities $\hat V_{ij}$, and I've derived that the covariance of this estimator is:

\begin{equation}
    C_{ij,gh} \equiv \langle (\hat V_{ij} - V_{ij}) ( \hat V_{gh} - V_{gh}) \rangle
    = \frac{1}{2N} \left[ V_{ig} V_{jh} + V_{ih} V_{jg} \right],
\end{equation}

where the angular brackets represent an ensemble average and $N$ is a constant.

**My question** is, can anyone see a way to get an analytical inverse for the covariance, $(C^{-1})_{ij,gh}$?  If it helps, I only actually need the diagonal of the inverse.

Note that to be invertible, you have to impose that $j \le i$ and $g \le h$, since $V_{ij}$ is symmetric.

If it helps, I've run the $1 \le i \le 2$ case through a symbolic computer algebra system (sympy) with the following result (indices orderd $[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]$):

$$
{\bf C}^{-1} = N\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{V_{2 2}^{2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}} & - \frac{2 V_{1 2} V_{2 2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}} & \frac{V_{1 2}^{2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}}\\- \frac{2 V_{1 2} V_{2 2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}} & \frac{2 V_{1 1} V_{2 2} + 2 V_{1 2}^{2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}} & - \frac{2 V_{1 1} V_{1 2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}}\\\frac{V_{1 2}^{2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}} & - \frac{2 V_{1 1} V_{1 2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}} & \frac{V_{1 1}^{2}}{\left(V_{1 1} V_{2 2} - V_{1 2}^{2}\right)^{2}}\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Sympy grinds to a halt for the $1 \le i \le 3$ case though.